# Merging data frames into another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with R statistics. I'm trying to make a data frame that merges other three data frames. Those three data frames have different column names & different row numbers (they don't have row names).

I tried originally to do:

```
 Namenewdf <- data.frame(dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3)
```

R marked an error because of differing number of rows.

Then I tried with the merge function but it also didn't work.

How do I merge the data frames so that the resulting data frames include the original information of the data frames used as arguments, not filling the 'void' rows from the data frames that have fewer rows?

Comment: Are you hoping to combine them column-wise (`cbind`) or row-wise (`rbind`)?

Comment: give a minimal reproducible example please

Comment: I want to keep the information of each data frame separated. I want to export that resulting data frame into an excel file from R, and I want to be able to see the information of each data frame in the same book.

Comment: Heh. I was about to make a snarky comment that you should instead use Excel and then I read your comment. You should store as an R list and then run `write.csv` on that list using `lapply` with `append=TRUE`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
library(rowr)
finaldataframe<-cbind.fill(dataframe1,dataframe2, dataframe3,fill = NA)
finaldataframe[is.na(finaldataframe)]<-""
```